# dimension inequality for graded versus non-graded polynomial rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A=k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ be a polynomial ring over an algebraically closed field $k$. Let $I$ be an ideal of $A$ and $f$ some element of $A$. Then the Krull dimension **does not** necessarily satisfy the relation
\begin{align}
(*): \, \dim \frac{A}{I+(f)} \ge \dim \frac{A}{I}-1.
\end{align} As an example take $A=k[x,y,z], \, I=(xz,yz), \, f=z-1$. 
In that case $\dim A/I = 2$, but $\dim A/(I+(f))=0$.

If however $I$ is a homogeneous ideal and $f$ a homogeneous element, then $(*)$ is true (i deduce this from Theorem 3 of Chapter 9 in Cox et al., Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms).

**Question:** How can this phenomenon be explained on an abstract level? What is it that we "gain" in terms of Krull dimension by viewing $A$ as a graded ring with its homogeneous ideals that we don't have if we view $A$ as a non-graded ring with arbitrary ideals? Alternatively, why does the graded ring $A$ behave more "smoothly" in terms of dimension than the non-graded $A$? Is it because with the grading $A$ becomes a $^*$local ring?

Comment: I get $\dim A/I = 2$ by $(x z,y z) = (x,y) (z)$.

Comment: @JürgenBöhm: Yes you are right, that was a typo. I fixed it, thanks.

Comment: I think you gave the best answer to your question: the property holds for local (and *local) rings, but fails for non-local rings.

Comment: I'm not so sure. The proof I know for local rings uses the Krull-Chevalley-Samuel theorem on dimension.

Comment: I see what you mean. The Krull-Chevalley-Samuel theorem must be what Matsumura calls "the fundamental theorem of dimension theory".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, when you consider $k[x,y,z]$ as an ungraded ring, you are viewing it as *affine* space $\mathbb A^3$, whereas when you view it as a graded ring, you are considering the *projective* space $\mathbb P^2$.  The precise reasons for this might not become clear until you study schemes, but you should be used to considering homogeneous ideals when you talk about projective space and considering general ideals when you talk about affine space.

The *affine* variety $V(xz,yz)$ has dimension $2$, since it is the union of a the plane $\{z=0\}$ with the line $\{x=y=0\}$.  When we intersect it with a hyperplane $V(f)$ (automatically of dimension $2$) we expect the intersection $V(I=(f))$ to have dimension at least $1$, since two varieties of dimension $2$ in $3$-dimensional space should intersect in at least a line.

What goes wrong in the affine case is that the dimension-$2$ part of $V(xy,yz)$ - i.e., $V(z)$ - is *parallel* to the hyperplane $V(z-1)$, so they don't meet at all!  The only point in the intersection $V(xy,yz,z-1)$ is the intersection of $V(z-1)$ with the line $V(x,y)$ at $(0,0,1)$.

Since projective space is 'the space where parallel lines meet', this phenomenon does not occur in the projective space: two varieties of codimension $d_1,d_2$ always meet in a subvariety of codimension at most $d_1+d_2$.

Comment: Your answer is nice and i am upvoting it. Indeed, Cox et al. give a similar geometric explanation. However, what i am interested in is a general algebraic argument. Why does the graded ring $A$ behave more "smoothly" in terms of dimension than the non-graded $A$?

Comment: I was just reading your algebraic argument but then you deleted it. Anyway, if you re-write it, then please also give a proof of your proposition.

Comment: I would be very interested to see a proof of your proposition, if such exists.

Comment: @Manos Hi!  I removed the algebraic argument because my proposition was false (indeed, it fails when applied to your example).  When I get some time in the next few days I'll work out what the correct statement and proof should be.

Comment: Ok, i look forward to it :)